# Can we redirect an external API call by direct IP address to another IP using wampserver?

Tags: windows-10, ip, redirection, wamp

I'm developing a PHP web application using wampserver. This application interact with an ERP with a direct IP access.

The IP changes depending on local testing and production environnement.

I want to avoid adding a rule in the application switching the IP depending on the context (local, production).

Is there a way to redirect an IP using Wampserver or if needed Windows 10?

Comment: This question is unclear at first. The title makes sound like you want your server to redirect clients to another IP. I did not flag it beacuse I understood what you were asking for, however you should edit your question as you may recieve some downvotes.

Comment: I've edited the title. Is it clear enough for you? Thank you for the suggestion.